# Datepicker Asp.Net

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net, .net

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação e gostaria de colocar o campo de data que quando for clicado ele exibe um calendário para seleção neste estilo: [datapicker](https://jqueryui.com/datepicker/), mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Esta é a minha primeira aplicação, este código funciona perfeitamente em .net?

Comment: Ok muito obrigado irei tentar

Answer (score 1):

Vou colocar em passos.

## jQuery UI

Verifique se o [jQuery UI](https://www.nuget.org/packages/jQuery.UI.Combined/) está instalado na sua solução. Abra o Package Manager Console (<kbd>View</kbd> > <kbd>Other Windows</kbd> > <kbd>Package Manager Console</kbd>) e digite:

```
PM> Install-Package jQuery.UI.Combined
```

Verifique se existe um *Bundle* pra ele (`App_Start/BundleConfig.cs`):

```
bundles.Add(new ScriptBundle("~/bundles/jqueryui").Include(
                    "~/Scripts/jquery-ui-{version}.js"));
```

Verifique se este *Bundle* está na *View* que terá o `datepicker` ou então se ele está em `Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml`:

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryui")
```

## Inicializando

Na *View*, adicione um *script* via `@section` para inicializar o `datepicker`:

```
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $(".datepicker").datepicker({
                autoclose: true,
                format: "dd/mm/yyyy",
                language: "pt-BR"
            });
        });
    </script>
}
```

Isto faz com que tudo que esteja marcado com a classe `datepicker` receba o comportamento visual de um `datepicker`.

Esta parte será renderizada no layout onde estiver marcado o seguinte:

```
@RenderSection("scripts", required: false)
```

## Inserindo `Datepickers`

O melhor componente pra inserir é o `TextBoxFor`. É possível usar `EditorFor`, mas não recomendo porque alguns comportamentos estranhos podem surgir:

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Data, new { @class = "form-control datepicker", placeholder = "Minha Data" })
```

Fazendo este roteiro, o `datepicker` deve funcionar.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode usar HTML5, é bem simples

```html
<input type="date">
```

PS: não compatível com o IE